# Pjsua и multifon, ошибка 408 Connection timeout

Tags: python, sip

Доброго времени суток. Пытаюсь подружить PJSUA и Multifon от Мегафона.

Код:

```
import sys
import pjsua as pj
import threading


def log_cb(level, str, len):
    print str

class MyAccountCallback(pj.AccountCallback):
    sem = None

    def __init__(self, account):
        pj.AccountCallback.__init__(self, account)

    def wait(self):
        self.sem = threading.Semaphore(0)
        self.sem.acquire()


    def on_reg_state(self):
        if self.sem:
            self.sem.release()

lib = pj.Lib()

try:
    lib.init(log_cfg = pj.LogConfig(level=0, callback=log_cb))
    lib.create_transport(pj.TransportType.UDP, pj.TransportConfig(5080))
    lib.start()

    acc = lib.create_account(pj.AccountConfig(username='79xxxxxxxxx', password='my_pass', domain='multifon.ru'))

    acc_cb = MyAccountCallback(acc)
    acc.set_callback(acc_cb)
    acc_cb.wait()

    print "\n"
    print "Registration complete, status=", acc.info().reg_status, \
          "(" + acc.info().reg_reason + ")"

    lib.destroy()
    lib = None

except pj.Error, e:
    print "Exception: " + str(e)
    lib.destroy()
```

В ответ все время получаю `408 Connection timeout`:

```
16:46:21.658    pjsua_acc.c  ...SIP registration failed, status=408 (Request Timeout)
16:46:21.658    pjsua_acc.c  ...Scheduling re-registration retry for acc 0 in 1 seconds..
408

Registration complete, status= 408 (Request Timeout)
```

Пробовал в код подставлять настройки для других провайдеров - все работает
нормально. Если вбить мегафоновские настройки в Zoiper - регистрация тоже проходит нормально. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел решение проблемы.

Строчку

```
acc = lib.create_account(pj.AccountConfig(username='79xxxxxxxxx', password='my_pass', domain='multifon.ru'))
```

нужно заменить на

```
acc = lib.create_account(pj.AccountConfig(username='79xxxxxxxxx', password='my_pass', domain='multifon.ru', proxy='sip:193.201.229.35:5060')
```

Здесь `193.201.229.35` - IP адрес, соответствующий доменному адресу `sbc.megafon.ru`

И пара замечаний по коду:

1) Вместо явного указания в поле `proxy` IP-адреса лучше использовать функцию `socket.gethostbyname`:

```
proxy_ip = socket.gethostbyname('sbc.megafon.ru')
proxy_str = 'sip:%s:%s' % (proxy_ip, port)

acc = lib.create_account(pj.AccountConfig(username=sip_login, password=sip_password,
                                                   domain=sip_domain, proxy=proxy_str))
```

2) В строке `lib.create_transport(pj.TransportType.UDP, pj.TransportConfig(5080))` вместо указания конкретного порта можно указать `0` - тогда операционная система сама выберет свободный порт.

Comment: Ясно. Сама библиотека не умеет пользоваться DNS вообще и адрес прокси ей надо было предоставить в виде IP и номера порта.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка 408 означает, что от сервера не поступило никакого ответа на посланный ему запрос (и, согласно спецификации протокола, несколько раз повторенный). Самое вероятное - запросы отправляются не туда, куда надо. Проверить проще всего с помощью сетвого дампа, сравнив трафик Zoiper и вашего приложения.

Попробуйте вместо multifon.ru указать sbc.multifon.ru. Если ошибка будет другой, то, возможно, библиотека не использует SRV записи в DNS или требует явного указания адреса прокси сервера (отдельно от домена регистрации).

Comment: Попробовал указать sbc.multifon.ru - получил `500 (Internal Server Error)`. Теперь попробую сравнить дампы. Спасибо за отклик.

Comment: 500 - это, по крайней мере, ответ с сервера. Попробуйте указать domain='multifon.ru', proxy='sbc.multifon.ru'

Comment: Попробовал, получаю ошибку: `pjsua_core.c  .Invalid route URI: sbc.multifon.ru;lr

Exception: Object: Lib, operation=create_account(), error=Invalid URI (PJSIP_EINVALIDURI)`

Comment: Наверное оно требует указания протокола в параметре прокси: proxy='sip:sbc.multifon.ru'. Я, к сожалению, совсем не знаю этой библиотеки.

Comment: Попробовал - теперь опять `500`-я ошибка. Но хоть в чем-то есть прогресс - раньше у меня с proxy ничего не получалось. Спасибо за подсказку с `sip:` :)